# Hibernate many One To Many relation in one class

Tags: java, hibernate

i have three entity and Main(User) enitiy is in relation with other two entity,how can i retrive list of three entities from database in one query using hibernate

```
package hib.test;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Country {
    private Integer id;
    private String country;
    private Set<User> userList = new HashSet<User>();

    public Country() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Set<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(Set<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

}
```

User.java

```
package hib.test;

public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private UserType userType;
    private Country country;

    public User() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UserType getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

UserType.java

```
package hib.test;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class UserType {
    private Integer id;
    private String userType;
    private Set<User> userList = new HashSet<User>();

    public UserType() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public Set<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(Set<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

}
```

country.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jun 6, 2012 1:12:01 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hib.test.Country" table="COUNTRY">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="country" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="COUNTRY" />
        </property>
        <set name="userList" table="USER" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="hib.test.User" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

user.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jun 6, 2012 1:12:01 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hib.test.User" table="USER">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="userType" class="hib.test.UserType" fetch="join">
            <column name="USERTYPE" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="country" class="hib.test.Country" fetch="join">
            <column name="COUNTRY" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

usertype.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jun 6, 2012 1:12:01 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hib.test.UserType" table="USERTYPE">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="userType" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="USERTYPE" />
        </property>
        <set name="userList" table="USER" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="hib.test.User" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can i retrive `List<User>`, `List<Country>` and `List<UserType>` with one query

EDIT

```
public static List<UserType> getUserTypeList() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    List<UserType> list = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        list = session.createQuery("from UserType as u").list();
        if (list != null) {
            for (UserType uType : list)
                Hibernate.initialize(uType.getUserList());
        }
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Actually I have 1 JTable and Two combo box each for UserType and Country
So when i select any data in combo box JTable data should be filter according to selected value and in memory it shoud be save selected UserType and Country object.

Comment: what do you mean by list,list and list??

Comment: list of user , list of UserType and list of Country

Comment: What exactly should the query return? The list of all the countries, the list of all the users, and the list of all the user types?

Comment: please write your query also.

Comment: So, in fact, you would like to get a list of all the user types, with the users of each user type, and the country of each user of each user type. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You need three queries to do that:

```
select u from User u;
select ut from UserType ut;
select c from Country c;
```

EDIT:

If what you actually want is a list of all the user types, with the users of each user type, and the country of each user of each user type, all this loaded in a single query, then you need fetch joins, as explained in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins):

```
select userType from UserType userType
left join fetch userType.users user
left join fetch user.country
```

Comment: if i select one userType how can i get list of user of same userType from above list

Comment: Why would you need to relate them? Hibernate does it for you. Ask for a country's users, and Hibernate will return them. To get the users of a userType, you call `userType.getUsers()`.

Comment: @JBNizet he has `lazy="true"` so if hibernate session is expired and he try to do `userType.getUsers()` it will fire run time exception.

Comment: @SatyajitsinhRaijada: yes, but the OP didn't ask for being able to do that once the session is closed. I still fail to usnderstand what he wants.

Comment: he just want every thing at once, now fatch type is lazy so during opened session he is able to do `userType.getUsers()` but if he try doing latter on as say out side of DAO hibernate will fire exception. actually he dont know about all this thing i am specifying just for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

if you want relational data at once and memory is not an issue, do `lazy="false"`

Answer (score 0):

try defining fetch type to EAGER on you user mapping, that way when you load your user it will load the country and userType.